1980's sci-fi cop movie with a smart house that uses sound to immobilize intruders
I'm looking for a specific movie I think from the 80s.
I can only remember one scene.
The set up (as much as I can remember): set in the future, a man on the run who I think is a current day police officer, but  is on the run from both bad guys and the future police force - I think he is tracking down a killer(s) / bad guys.
The part I remember:

There is a "smart home" that talks back and is activated by voice.
When he enters, he greets the house by a name but can't remember it.
I think he is hiding out in this house from police and/or bad guys.
It has an intruder alarm which omits a high pitch noise to debilitate any intruders.
As someone breaks in to steal or hurt the owners, the owner can say a command i.e., "lights off", "alarm activate" and the house will start up a high-pitched alarm.
The home owner has a certain type of earplug only built for the pitch for that alarm, so they can insert their earplugs before the alarm goes off.
In the scene, this happens where police officers or an intruder breaks in and the main character is one step ahead and has a pair of earplugs, but he doesn't know if they will work for the home he is in.
The intruder/ police are crippled on the floor.
The police are provided with earplugs which are universal, so that in the event they respond to a house that is being burglarised, they can enter and the bad guys are crippled by the piercing sound of the intruder alarm.
The main man in the film (possibly a policeman from this time) steals the universal earplugs and is able to escape.

Apologies that this is all I can remember, but it has been on my mind a good few years.
So far I've ruled out:

Timecop (1994)
Minority Report (2002)
Equilibrium (2002)
Demolition Man (1993)
The Running Man (1987)
RoboCop (1987)
Escape from New York (1981)
Escape from L.A. (1996)
Dead Heat (1988)
Runaway (1984)
Blade Runner (1982)
Looper (2012)

Hope that helps! There’s a possibility it could be 90s, but I'm sure it was an 80s vibe.

Possibly TekWar series of films. It was started in 1994 and ran to 1996.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TekWar_episodes#Season_1_.281994.29
Why it might match:

ex-cop then convict then corporate enforcer as a protagonist
Mildly futuristic cyberpunk setting with "how 80s imagined future would look like" vibe
Everybody is using sonic weapons instead of guns and some of those are mounted inside houses.
In one episode (I don't remember which, I think it was "Skin Deep" from season 2) main character enters a house produced by megacorporation he is working for and activates its defense systems. He is on the run from the police at the moment.

